# Using @query with LitElement and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element

I'm trying to do this:

```
@query('#gist')
gist: HTMLIFrameElement;
```

And the typescript linting says:

> Property 'gist' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

How do we clear this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `!` after the property name. This tells Typescript that the value will be set.

```
@query('#gist')
gist!: HTMLIFrameElement|null;
```

Comment: You rock!!  Welcome to SO!!

Comment: I'd like to stress that this is quite important to get right. In order to make TS compiler happy, I initially wrote `gist?: HTMLIFrameElement` (using same name as current example). But that led me to error, as then I was checking if `typeof this.gist !== 'undefined'`, while to be effective (and correct) I should check if `this.gist !== null`